# getting next 10 data elements, sorted in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

A very simple question say i have the following models:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
   entry = Models.CharField()
   time_of_entry = Models.DateTimeField()
```

in my view i do the following:

```
def get_tweets(request):
    tw = Tweet.objects.all().order_by(-time_of_entry)
```

this will return me the tweets ordered in descending order by time.

when i filter it this way, say there are 150 tweets arranged in variable tw.
Is there any way i can get tweets in range 20 to 30 of the above queryset?

I want to show 10 tweets at a time, from the above list, and then in my template i want to have a simple button, which reads `load_10_next_tweets` and does the same. I do not want to use pagination.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways. The first is to [get an iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) and then [islice it](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) multiple times. The second is to slice the query set itself, e.g. `tw[20:30]`.